# Messenger - JavaScript error in the main process

Tags: 16.04, facebook, javascript, instant-messaging

I have installed the [Messenger for Desktop](https://messengerfordesktop.com/) app on my 16.04. Everytime I launch the application I get this javascript error seing on screenshot below

[image]

However when I click OK the the app launches properly. I haven't detected any issues so far, however I was wondering if anyone else has faced the same issue and how to solve it.

**Edit** I have noticed that I don't get a notification or any indication when some of my contacts texts me when the app is minimized. I'm not sure if this is a bug occured from this issue or whether is missing from the linux version in general (which probablly is still a bug)

Comment: I have the same issue. It happened for first time about a week agoo.

Comment: So its probably a bug of the app??

Comment: I just write a feedback (Help->Send Feedback) with the following content: *Hello, I'm using Messenger for Desktop v2.0.9-stable on Ubuntu 16.04, a week ago the app started to throw the following error message: JavaScript error in the main process. Also some conversations doesn't show. Please see this Question on AU: `https://askubuntu.com/q/1022676/566421`*

Comment: Lykos, try to switch off the option *"Check for Update Automatically"* from the menu *"App"*, I suppose this could suppress the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Temporal workaround that I found is to switch off the option *"Check for Update Automatically"* from the menu *"App"*. This will suppress the message *"JavaScript error in the main process"*. In result the overall behaviour of the application will be improved.

[image]

Further when I check for updates manually, *"Checking for Update..."* process never finish (as you can see on the image above) or finish with the following error message.

[image]

Apparently there is a problem with their update server.

Answer (score 1):

I got this and it worked fine.

Switch update channel to DEV and download the new update. After installing new update, the application should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this error is very annoying. I did the following:
I downloaded the package

```
messengerfordesktop-2.0.9-linux64.tar.gz
```

and unpacked it into a separate folder, which I put in the `TEMP`. Then I created a launch shortcut on the desktop. Everything does work fine and without the boring window, as it always worked.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

If you click OK and app won't start, go to app directory (you can find it out by typing `which messengerfordesktop`) and try run the app as root. App will start, then uncheck "*Check for Update Automatically*" as **pa4080** proposed. It solved the problem on my Kubuntu 18.04.